# How to add caption and sum a column?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i want give caption DATE,PRICE1, PRICE2 and i also show sum of price1, price2 in the footer. how can i do  this?

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCari" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBelgeTarihi"><%#(Eval("DATE","{0:d}"))%></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblAlacakTutar"><%#ValidationHelper.FormatPrice(ValidationHelper.GetDecimal(Eval("PRICE1"), 0))%></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblBorcTutar"><%#ValidationHelper.FormatPrice(ValidationHelper.GetDecimal(Eval("PRICE2"), 0))%></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've HeaderTemplate and FooterTemplate as child elements of Repeater.